# Unable to run logstash config file (permission denied)

Tags: file-permissions, ubuntu-14.04, elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

my config file is stored in

```
/etc/logstash/
```

and I ran the command

```
$ /etc/logstash -f /etc/logstash/logstash.conf
```

as root.

However, they told me that permission denied when I tried to do that. Is there any way to solve this?

Comment: Are you sure you ran it as root? The `$` at the beginning of the line makes it seem like you didn't.

Comment: Please run command: "type logstash"

Comment: `/etc/logstash` is a directory, not a program. You are trying to run the directory. You need to use the path to the actual program first in your command.

Answer (score 1):

The way to solve this is to use the correct path to the `logstash` executable. According to your description `/etc/logstash` is a directory, not an executable file, so you cannot use that as a command.